# HTML / <select> tag / char encoding

Tags: html, character-encoding, html-select

I have already set char encoding to UTF-8 in the meta tag, but for some reason
the characters are still broken in the `<select>` options.

`<select name="county" style="font-size:100%;" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="budapest">Budapest</option>
    <option value="pest">Pest county</option>
    <option value="vas">Vas county</option>
    <option value="bacskiskun">Bács-Kiskun county</option>
    <option value="fejer">Fejér county</option>
    <option value="hajdu">Hajdú-bihar county</option>
</select>`

What should i do?

Thanks

Comment: can you add a sample of the content of your `<select>`. Adding snippet will be help

Comment: @SUJEETJAISWAL sample added.

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/eugenefedoto/pen/oxRxEe

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<select>
  <option value="ÿ">ÿ</option>
  <option value="æ">æ</option>
  <option value="$">$</option>
  <option value="Ñ">Ñ</option>
</select>
```

Does that work for you? If you're serving files from a server, the server's response header could be returning something other than UTF-8.

Comment: I have set character encoding to UTF-8 in the response object: `response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");` and still not working.

Comment: Make sure your text editor is saving in UTF-8. Also Check that you're getting the correct response for the Document file: http://i.imgur.com/zAUYBSN.png